# Unity iOS background audio getting muted

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, mobile

I disabled the "Mute other Audio Sources" option in the iOS player settings, but still every time I start my game the background music (e.g. Spotify) is being paused. Strangely, on Android is everything working fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm fighting with this problem also. Did you found any solution? For me little improvement gave the advice found somewhere to put: `PlayerSettings.muteOtherAudioSources = false;` before:
`BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(buildPlayerOptions);`
(own editor script to launch build) Improvement is that starting my UnityApp let the background music play but till I'm initializing mic. So, it is a sign that the problem is not only ignoring Mute Other Audio Sources checkbox, but different behaviour of audio system.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an issue with this Unity release, I voted on it here and waiting for Unity to fix it.

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-unity-player-does-not-respect-the-mute-other-audio-sources-toggle-in-player-settings